# How to re-route correctly in React.js? Always renders white page

Tags: reactjs

When I visit my default url `http://localhost:3000/` React is rendering the `Landing` component which makes sense to me. I'm using `react-router-v6`.

```
// App.js

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now in the Landing component I do have more `Route`s which however don't render anything but a white page like e.g. `Team` (I removed imports from code, all is properly imported).

```
// Landing.js

function Landing(props) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <CoreWrapper>
                <div className={styles.landingWrapper}>Test</div>
              </CoreWrapper>

            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/team" element={<Team />} />
                <Route exact path="/careers" element={<Careers />} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            </Routes>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Landing;
```

```
// CoreWrapper.js

const CoreWrapper = (props) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Header/>
            <div className={styles.bodyWrapper}>{props.children}</div>
            <Footer/>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default CoreWrapper
```

```
// Team.js

const Team = () => {
    return (
        <CoreWrapper>
            <div className="teamWrapper">Team Here</div>
        </CoreWrapper>
    )
}

export default Team;
```

Comment: I think the problem is coming because you put '/team' in the route inside of Landing.js so because of that you will need //teams to see the page. Try keeping just 'team' and see if that works.

Comment: When you have `exact path="/"` for your landing component, paths like `/team` don’t match. Therefore the Landing component doesn’t render and you don’t get the sub-routes.

Comment: @rayhatfield ah that makes sense. So what would be a typical schema? To include all routes into App.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `react-router v6` version then `exact` doesn't support anymore

I assume you put `BrowserRouter` at root component.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
function Landing(props) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <CoreWrapper>
                <div className={styles.landingWrapper}>Test</div>
              </CoreWrapper>

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} />
                <Route path="/careers" element={<Careers />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                // make whatever default routes of landing component that's your choice
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/team" />} />
            </Routes>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Landing;
```

but that's the official documented way of doing it I suggest you also do like the documentation way

[nested-routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes)

Comment: and yeah also search what is `outlet` in `react-router` then you don't need `CoreWrapper` explicit define it where routes are define

Comment: thanks, when I now visit /team it is rendered below the landing page so I now have two headers + footers etc. -- why's that? Also what is `Navigate to`? Can't find anything in the dosc

Comment: because you are using `CoreWrapper` in `landing component` as well as in `team component` .